# WP8 - SkyDrive API. Checking if folder exists?

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, onedrive

Is there any way i can check if a folder exists in a users SkyDrive account at location "me/SkyDrive" ?

Basically I just want to know how I can do this because my app has the skydrive functionality and the user can upload a file if they want to a folder in "me/Skydrive". But I've added the create folder each time the user has logged into their SkyDrive account. This is causing the upload functionality to break since each team it creates a folder, it generates a new folder id which has errors when uploading.

But main point is **is there a way to check if a folder with the exact name exists in the SkyDrive directory? if so how?**

Here's my code soo far which basically just logs the user in and creates a folder:

```
private async void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {                      
            session = e.Session;
            client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
            StatusforSKD.Text = "You have signed in.";
            try
            {
                var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                folderData.Add("name", "File List");
                LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
                LiveOperationResult operationResult = await liveClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
                dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
                InfoDD.Text = result.id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
    }
    else
    {
        StatusforSKD.Text = "Not signed in.";
        client = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about this

- create recursive, async function which calls and awaits the 'Get'
  function on the LiveConnectClient with ?filter=folders appended to
  the query location.  for each item returned check it's name if it
  matches return true, otherwise call function again if no matches
  return false.

this link doesnt contain codes. just info
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/78b0a9b4-bd1b-452f-95fb-5b3acfa6866c/checking-folder-existence-in-skydrive-with-livesdk?forum=messengerconnect

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch the exception you can do something like this:

```
if (exception.Message.Contains("already exists")
{
 // ignore error and carry one because the folder already exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private async Task GetSkyDriveFolder()
    {
        if (liveClient == null)
            await SignIn();

        //the session is already established, so let's find our folder by its name
        LiveOperationResult result = await liveClient.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files/");
        List<object> data = (List<object>)result.Result["data"];
        foreach (IDictionary<string, object> content in data)
        {
            if (content["name"].ToString() == folderName)
            {
                //The folder has been found!
                folderID = content["id"].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Folder exists hurray");

            }
        }


    }
```

this will check whether folder exists or not in skydrive